# How can I do the equivalent of Google App Engine's helloworld.py in Amazon EC2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am very new to Amazon AWS.  I would like to do the most basic thing to start, which is to make a webpage display hello world, using python.

In Google App Engine this is fairly straightforward and is outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld).

Inside helloworld.py, something called webapp2, which has a [web server gateway interface](http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial).  When there is a request, there is a response with the HTTP header, content type, and the "hello world" message.

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

In another file (app.yaml), there is a simple configuration:

```
application: your-app-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.application
```

In this way it is really simple to get up and running.  Is there a way to do an equivalent to this using AWS?

To start, needed to set up the instance, which was straightforward.  For my case, I decided to use Amazon Linux because it said python in the description, and used a "t1 micro instance" that would allow me to take advantage of the "free tier" services, which is great for my low power low bandwidth learning purposes.

Then, I was able to use the keyfile to log in just fine, which left me sitting at the command prompt.

[]$ python -v

```
Python 2.6.9 (unknown, Mar 28 2014, 00:06:37) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/readline.so", 2);
import readline # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/readline.so
>>> 1+1
2
>>>
```

So, I created the linux instance, was able to fire up python.  Now what are the steps I should take to get to hello world, as I did with Google App Engine?  I should also note that webapp2 was not installed, and I suspect that other things I will want such as beautifulsoup/bs4 aren't either.

So I needed to install some packages, and getting pip worked like a charm:

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.1.tar.gz#md5=62a9f08dd5dc69d76734568a6c040508
tar -xvf pip*.gz
cd pip*
sudo python setup.py install
```

webapp2 seems like it is for Google App Engine - is there something similar I should be using?

Comment: According to webapp2 document, "webapp2 can also be used outside of Google App Engine, independently of the App Engine SDK."

Comment: AWS and GAE are completely different propositions. AWS is "infrastructure as a service": it just provides you with a machine. GAE is "platform as a service": it provides you with a platform to build your app with. Obviously, getting started on IaaS is going to be more involved than with PaaS.

Comment: However, webapp2 is a normal WSGI library, and can be used anywhere at all: but you wouldn't use app.yaml, which is a GAE thing only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a little long winded but [AWS provides a guide to using Flask with Python on Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_flask.html)... I think this would deliver what you'd like with minimal fuss.

Comment: Thanks - looking into it now.

Comment: wohoo!  hello world - it worked. thank you.   the instructions you posted are very concise.  i ran into only a few issues, and these were probably related to my developing linux skills.